# Can I automatically post earned badges to my Facebook status?

Tags: feature-request, badges, facebook

Wouldn't that be geeky if I could somehow associate my Stack Overflow account with Facebook in a way, that I could "push" earned badges to my Facebook Status?

Comment: "Wouldn't that be geeky" -- yes, yes it would.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API exposes your [current badges](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/users/521799/badges), so it's certainly possible to write something that does it. I poked around [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/); one app called [Stack Bragger](https://stackapps.com/questions/1163/stack-bragger-facebook-app-to-post-questions-badges) looks like what you want (I've never actually tried it). There's also a more involved app called [StackEngine](https://stackapps.com/questions/1422/stackengine-facebook-app-to-embed-reputation-badges-etc-from-user-stack-exch) that makes a whole new tab on your Facebook profile to hold SE information